# Pandas map a subset based on index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem which is probably best illustrated with the following example. This code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Place' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Name' : ['Fred', 'Fred', 'Gary', 'Gary', 'Tom', 'Tom'],
    'Price': [100, 200, 500, 1000, 20, 50]
})
```

produces the following dataframe

```
  Place  Name  Price
0     A  Fred    100
1     A  Fred    200
2     B  Gary    500
3     B  Gary   1000
4     B   Tom     20
5     B   Tom     50
```

In my problem, `['Place', 'Name']` constitutes a "primary key" (ie., a unique index). I would like to, for every primary key, create a new column: `'Price-String'`. `'Price-String'` describes the price: it can be either `'Small'` or `'Big'`. This description describes the prices relative to its own primary key, so while `50` is small compared to `1000`, `50` is big compared to `20`, and since `['B', 'Tom']` has only 20 and 50 for price, 20 should be small and 50 should be big.

In the exact format that I have it, this code works:

```
df['Price-String'] = np.tile(['Small', 'Big'], 3)
```

Which gives the desired output:

```
  Place  Name  Price Price-String
0     A  Fred    100        Small
1     A  Fred    200          Big
2     B  Gary    500        Small
3     B  Gary   1000          Big
4     B   Tom     20        Small
5     B   Tom     50          Big
```

And this is fine if the problem can be reduced to the first dataframe (which it typically can using `sort_values`). However, this breaks even for just this simply variation:

```
  Place  Name  Price
0     A  Fred    100
1     A  Fred    200
2     B  Gary    500
3     B  Gary   1000
4     B   Tom     20
5     B   Tom     50
6     B   Tom     50
```

Is there a convenient pandas way to attack this problem? In summary, I need to do the following:

1. Identify the unique `'Prices'` for each primary key,
2. Sort these unique `'Prices'`,
3. Replace (or add a new column) using the mapping outlined.

**Note**: In this basic example, I have used n=2 prices for each key, and an associated list `['Small', 'Big']` but in practice there can be any number of items. You can assume that there will be n unique prices for every key, where n is the length of the associated list.

Comment: I guess you can groupby the key and apply a ratio-ing function

Answer (score 0):

You can Groupby the key, and apply a ratio-ing function.
Something like:

```
>>> df['Price_Ratio']=df.groupby(['Place','Name']).Price.apply(lambda x: x/max(x))
>>> df
  Place  Name  Price  Price_Ratio
0     A  Fred    100          0.5
1     A  Fred    200          1.0
2     B  Gary    500          0.5
3     B  Gary   1000          1.0
4     B   Tom     20          0.4
5     B   Tom     50          1.0
```